# Can python do "from package import module.symbol_name"?

Tags: python, syntax, module, python-import, python-module

According to http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement,
We can use

> from module import identifier

and identifier can be module.name

But python suggest an syntax error, is there a mistake in the document?

Comment: Please post the exact import statement that you are using. And there is no mistake in the document.

Comment: There cannot be a mistake as it _is_ the reference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`identifier` cannot contain periods.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) Your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Side note: a sequence of identifiers separated by dots is a `dotted_name` in the [grammar](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html).